# Sending Json Object to kafka topic in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to send Json Object to my kafka topic but I am facing some problem

I use pojo with single instance variable as fileName where I am setting the filename and sending to Kafka Topic.

```
 KafkaJsonSend objSend= new KafkaJsonSend();
            objSend.setFileName(filename);

          //Configure the Producer
            Properties configProperties = new Properties();
            configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"10.10.51.10:9092");
            configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonSerializer.class);

            Producer<String, JsonNode> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, JsonNode>(configProperties);

            JsonNode  jsonNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(objSend);
            ProducerRecord<String, JsonNode> rec = new 

            ProducerRecord<String, JsonNode>("BlueShifts",jsonNode);
            producer.send(rec);

            producer.close();
```

But when I run this code I am getting exception which is continuously getting logged in my console.

```
Error: Uncaught error in kafka producer I/O thread

IllegalStateException: No entry found for connection 0
```

[image: Kafka Error in java]

I have also tried with spring kafka but I got this in console

```
2019-02-04 16:43:13.938  INFO 4432 --- [nio-6020-exec-1]
o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values:
        acks = 1
        batch.size = 16384
        block.on.buffer.full = false
        bootstrap.servers = [10.0.2.15:9092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.id =
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        interceptor.classes = null
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        linger.ms = 0
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 0
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        timeout.ms = 30000
        value.serializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

2019-02-04 16:43:14.158  INFO 4432 --- [nio-6020-exec-1]
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka  version : 0.10.2.0
2019-02-04 16:43:14.160  INFO 4432 --- [nio-6020-exec-1]
o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka  commitId :
576d93a8dc0cf421 2019-02-04 16:44:14.206 ERROR 4432 ---
[nio-6020-exec-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and
payload='KafkaJsonSend [fileName=a0a7caf336e8481fb
6db2de70d39029e_1549278789987.mp3]' to topic BlueShifts:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Comment: When I am using Spring Kafka Template I am getting 
`Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='KafkaJsonSend [fileName=9aa7b9d2181b4137
b1f86762357e036d_1549274276827.mp3]' to topic BlueShifts:`

Comment: can you post entire stack trace when using spring kafka template ?

Comment: @kalimba added in my question at the bottom

Comment: thanks for showing error. can you confirm once kafka broker is actually running/accessible  on 10.10.51.10. If possible to log in to machine, try to monitor broker logs also. Timeout exception usually is indicator of some connection problem.

Comment: @kalimba https://pasteboard.co/HZAOcR0.png I have uploaded the broker list here. And how do I check if it's running on 10.10.51.10 ?

Comment: login to 10.10.51.10 and do `lsof -i :9092` if output is empty then your kafka broker is not running on 9092 port on that machine

Comment: @kalimba https://pasteboard.co/HZAU5UH.png see I got this it's not empty but why it's referring to other host like kafka:9052->localhost:47024 I didn't understand that is it fine?

Comment: @kalimba did you have anything on this yet? Is there anything related to proxy since I am connected to proxy

Comment: YES!! please check if this port is open and you are able to access it where you are running kafka producer. You can use telnet for this purpose.

Comment: @kalimba it's working when I send from another console as a producer the messages are coming but not from my java code....like I said it says key is null...what is the "key" here??

Comment: null key is fine, kafka automatically generates key based on payload.

Comment: @kalimba Worked added `10.10.51.10 kafka` at **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc** in hosts file and it worked in both ways....can you tell why it's mapped with kafka why it couldn't find with ip

Answer (score 0):

> Worked added `10.10.51.10 kafka` at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` in `hosts` file and it worked in both ways....can you tell why it's mapped with kafka why it couldn't find with ip

You need to configure your Kafka brokers correctly for your network: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: I am running kafka on oracle virtual box....I didn't configured anything it should picked the ip since it says if we do not mention any advertised.host.name or host.name then it picks the ip.....Please explain what to configure in my box

Comment: how to use kafkacat ?

Comment: How to use `kafkacat`: https://docs.confluent.io/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html

Comment: "Please explain what to configure in my box" -> read the article that I link to, it explains everything :)

Comment: `Much better is to understand and actually fix the advertised.listeners setting for your network.` it says this but where is the fix man....and kafkacat is the utility tool.....I am still not getting it...my console messages are logged properly....if you know the fix post that....I am getting what's happening now it was a good read but I want to fix it

Comment: I tried edit file producer.properties and used 10.10.51.10 instead of localhost but still not working....can you give me some hint I am not getting anything from your links

Comment: You need to change the configuration in your Kafka broker's configuration (e.g. `server.properties`), rather than in your producer.

Comment: I have tried that but not working.....can you specifically mention what to change

Comment: @Kramer `advertised.listeners` in `server.properties` needs to be set as an external IP of the VM. If you want a quickly installed VM environment, I would encourage using Vagrant - https://github.com/cricket007/cp-ansible/tree/addVagrant/vagrant